# How to remove hover style on Previous/Next links using Datatables

Tags: html, css, datatables

I am trying to remove the hover style on Previous/Next links in `DataTables` but for some reason it is not taking the affect. I want to simply show a transparent border on the images rather than black background on hover. How can I achieve this?

This is how it looks currently.

[image]

JQuery

```
var table = $('#esignTable').DataTable({"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
      pagingType: 'input',
      pageLength: 5,
      language: {
        "sEmptyTable": " ",
        oPaginate: {
            "sNext": '<img src="../images/integration/SlowRight.jpg">',
            "sPrevious": '<img src="../images/integration/SlowLeft.jpg">',
            "sFirst": '<img src="../images/integration/FastLeft.jpg">',
            "sLast": '<img src="../images/integration/FastRight.jpg">',
        }
      }   
    });
```

CSS

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info, .dataTables_length { 
display: none; 
}

.top {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-right: 41%;
}

.dataTables_paginate input {
 width: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
padding : 2px;
margin-left: 0px;
display: inline;
border: 0px;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

table.dataTable tr:nth-child(odd)  { 
background-color: #FFFACD;  
}

img:hover {
 border-radius: 0px;
 border: 1px solid #828282;
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion but if you use Firebug in Firefox it shows you what CSS is triggered when hovering over a page element.

Comment: I got all other classes using Chrome's developer tool. For hover it doesn't show anything. I know what you are saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it to work. DataTables has its won classes so I just modified them instead of changing the img.

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
   background: none;
   color: black!important;
   border-radius: 4px;
   border: 1px solid #828282;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:active {
   background: none;
   color: black!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see "img" at your CSS or "class" at your image elements ().

Comment: I've edited my question. I didn't copy the entire snippet.

Comment: Hello David. Just remove that "background-color" line and replace "#828282" with "transparent" and i guess that will solve the proble you've mentioned.

Comment: It didn't help Geza.

Comment: Hi! Mind if i ask what browser you are using, please? It worked under Chrome based browser (Comodo Dragon). You still had black result?

Comment: I use Chrome. In fact I've tested in Firefox and IE too same result.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
background-color:green;
}
img:hover {
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="FastRight.png">
This works under Microsoft Edge and Comodo Dragon. Can you spot a difference?
</body>
</html>

Comment: But it it not working for me. I am still having the same issue.

Comment: Can't this be a cache issue? Have you tried to empty your temporary browser storages? I mentioned this as i've just installed FF v54.0 64 bit and my above small code just works fine there. O.o

Comment: I cleared the cache. Cleaned tomcat directory but the black bg color doesn't go away.

Comment: If my little code isn't working either - as it works for me both under Chrome, Edge and FF - , then this might not be an issue with your code, but with a graphical setting (Alpha blending or such). If possible, you shall try your code under other computer.

Comment: It is taking all other styling but not just this. Your code works I checked it in Fiddle and I am doing the same thing. BG color is transparent but still the black color shows up.